Finding a basis for q-ary lattice $\Lambda^\perp(\mathbf{A})=\{ \mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{Z}^n \mid \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x} = 0 \mod{q} \}$
For a positive modulus $q$ and dimensions $m,n$, a $q$-ary lattice specified by a parity check matrix $\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{Z}^{m\times n}$ is defined as $\Lambda^\perp(\mathbf{A})=\{\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{Z}^n \mid \mathbf{A}\mathbf{x} = 0 \mod{q}\}$
We may equivalently look at it as $\Lambda^\perp(\mathbf{A}) = \ker(\varphi_\mathbf{A})$ where $\varphi_A: \mathbb{Z}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^m_q ; \mathbf{x} \mapsto \mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}\pmod q$.
Since $\Lambda^\perp(\mathbf{A})$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}^n$, we know it is finitely generated. However, how does one find a basis $\mathbf{B}$ that specifies it without making assumptions on $m,n,q$ or the structure of $\mathbf{A}$?
I've seen answers on other posts ([1], [2]) as well as lecture notes that make assumptions on the structure of the matrix $\mathbf{A}$ containing invertible submatrices.
Is it possible to give a constructive proof for the existence of a finite basis without making such assumptions?

We have
$$
\begin{align*}
x \in \Lambda^{\bot}(A) &\iff Ax = 0 \bmod q\\
&\iff Ax + qy = 0 \text{ for some } y \in \mathbb{Z}^m\\
&\iff \underbrace{[A \;|\; q\mathbb{I}_m] }_{B}
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y
\end{bmatrix} = 0
\end{align*}
$$
Therefore, $x \in \Lambda^{\bot}(A)$ if and only if there exists some $y \in \mathbb{Z}^m$ such that $B \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix} = 0$. Since, $B \in \mathbb{Z}^{m \times (n + m)}$ is an integer matrix, we can apply the Hermite Normal Form (HNF) reduction to obtain a full-rank matrix $C \in \mathbb{Z}^{m \times m}$ (because $B$ has rank $m$). For more details on HNF, refer this link.
The HNF guarantees the existence of a unimodular matrix $U \in \mathbb{Z}^{(m + n) \times (m + n)}$ (i.e., a matrix with integer entries and determinant ±1) such that $[C \;|\; 0] = BU$. Thus, we can write:
$$0 = B\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y
\end{bmatrix} = 
[C\;|\;0]\; U^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y
\end{bmatrix}
= [C\;|\;0]\; \begin{bmatrix}
z_1\\
z_2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Since $C$ is full-rank, we must have $z_1 = 0$. Therefore, for any $z_2 \in \mathbb{Z}^n$, the vector $\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ z_2 \end{bmatrix}$ is a solution. And, we have:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y
\end{bmatrix} = U\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
z_2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
This shows that for any $x \in \Lambda^{\bot}(A)$, there exists a $z_2$ and vice-versa (because $U$ is invertible). This implies that the set of all vectors $x \in \Lambda^{\bot}(A)$ forms a subspace generated by the columns of the block $U_{01}$ of the matrix $U$, where $U$ is partitioned as:
$$
U = \begin{bmatrix}
U_{00} & U_{01}\\
U_{11} & U_{11}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
such that $U_{00} \in \mathbb{Z}^{n \times m}$, $U_{01} \in \mathbb{Z}^{n \times n}$, $U_{10} \in \mathbb{Z}^{m \times m}$ and $U_{11} \in \mathbb{Z}^{m \times n}$. Therefore, $U_{01}$ is a basis for $\Lambda^{\bot}(A)$.
